# Cross-Validation and GridSearchCV score difference

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, data-science

I'm performing a LinearRegression, while applying a Cross-Validation analysis i get a better result than with GridSearch for the same parameters.
I should get the same result or a better one with GridSearch.I've tried different `refit` values for my gridseach and nothing seems to impouve the low value.

The Cross-Validation model give a score of 0.622:

```
logtransformer= FunctionTransformer(np.log, inverse_func = np.exp, check_inverse = True)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('logtrans',logtransformer,['surface']),
                                               ('scaler', StandardScaler(),['years', 'surface', 'steam_p', 'elec_p']),
                                              ('onehotencoder', OneHotEncoder(), ['type']), 
                                               ('ordinalencoder', OrdinalEncoder(),['nfloors'])])


parameters = {'fit_intercept':True, 'normalize':True}
pipeline3= Pipeline(steps =[('preprocessor', preprocessor),('model',TransformedTargetRegressor(
                                                                    regressor = LinearRegression(**parameters), 
                                                                    func = np.log,
                                                                    inverse_func = np.exp))])

scores_cv = cross_val_score(pipeline3, X_train, y_train, scoring='r2', cv=KFold(n_splits = 23, shuffle = True,random_state=100 ))
scores_cv.mean()
```

The GridSearchCV model gives a score max of 0.614

```
pipeline2= Pipeline(steps =[('preprocessor', preprocessor),('gridsearchcv', GridSearchCV(
                                                                TransformedTargetRegressor(
                                                                    regressor = LinearRegression(), 
                                                                    func = np.log,
                                                                    inverse_func = np.exp),
                                                                param_grid= {'regressor__fit_intercept':[True, False],'regressor__normalize': [True, False]},
                                                                cv = KFold(n_splits = 23, shuffle = True, random_state=100),
                                                                scoring = ('r2','neg_mean_absolute_error'),
                                                                return_train_score = True,
                                                                refit = 'r2' ))])model2 = pipeline2.fit(X_train, y_train)
model2 = pipeline2.fit(X_train, y_train)
pd.DataFrame(model2['gridsearchcv'].cv_results_).mean_test_r2.max()
```

Comment: A CV score difference of 0.008 seems like something you can overlook. What is your respective test data score?

Comment: Also, does the `preprocessor` have an impact? Consider adding it to the example.

Comment: @Kosmos The ```preprocessor``` is the same in both cases. I did not understand your question about test data, is true that there is not a big difference but i would love to know why? maybe there is some operation in the GridSearch constructor

Comment: I notice that the `scoring` for `GridSearchCV` contains two metrics. Perhaps the optimisations takes both into account which, in turns lowers the R2. Can you run it without neg_mean_absolut_error?

Comment: I run the model without ```neg_mean_absolut_error``` and i got the same score.